# Terraform environments - how to get it DRY

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, terraform

We are utilizing Terraform heavily for AWS Cloud provisioning. Our base terraform structure looks like this:

```
├─ modules
├── x
├── y
├─ environments
├── dev
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── output.tf
│   └── variables.tf
└── uat
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── output.tf
│   └── variables.tf
└── prod
    ├── main.tf
    ├── output.tf
    └── variables.tf
```

As we reached a point where we have many modules and many environments, code duplication becomes a more serious headache now, we would like to get rid of as much of it as possible.

Our main concern currently is with the `output.tf` files - every time we extend an existing module or add a new module, we need to set up the environment specific configuration for it (this is expected), but we still have to copy/paste the required parts into `output.tf` to output the results of the provisioning (like IP addresses, AWS ARNs, etc.).

Is there a way to get rid of the duplicated `output.tf` files? Could we just define the wanted outputs in the modules themselves and see all defined outputs whenever we run terraform for a specific environment?

Answer (score 6):

We built and open sourced [Terragrunt](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt) to solve this very issue. One of Terragrunt's features is the ability to download remote Terraform configurations. The idea is that you define the Terraform code for your infrastructure just once, in a single repo, called, for example, `modules`:

```
└── modules
 ├── app
 │   └── main.tf
 ├── mysql
 │   └── main.tf
 └── vpc
     └── main.tf
```

This repo contains typical Terraform code, with one difference: anything in your code that should be different between environments should be exposed as an input variable. For example, the app module might expose the following variables:

```
variable "instance_count" {
  description = "How many servers to run"
}

variable "instance_type" {
  description = "What kind of servers to run (e.g. t2.large)"
}
```

In a separate repo, called, for example, live, you define the code for all of your environments, which now consists of just one `.tfvars` file per component (e.g. `app/terraform.tfvars`, `mysql/terraform.tfvars`, etc). This gives you the following file layout:

```
└── live
    ├── prod
    │   ├── app
    │   │   └── terraform.tfvars
    │   ├── mysql
    │   │   └── terraform.tfvars
    │   └── vpc
    │       └── terraform.tfvars
    ├── qa
    │   ├── app
    │   │   └── terraform.tfvars
    │   ├── mysql
    │   │   └── terraform.tfvars
    │   └── vpc
    │       └── terraform.tfvars
    └── stage
        ├── app
        │   └── terraform.tfvars
        ├── mysql
        │   └── terraform.tfvars
        └── vpc
            └── terraform.tfvars
```

Notice how there are no Terraform configurations (`.tf` files) in any of the folders. Instead, each `.tfvars` file specifies a `terraform { ... }` block that specifies from where to download the Terraform code, as well as the environment-specific values for the input variables in that Terraform code. For example, `stage/app/terraform.tfvars` may look like this:

```
terragrunt = {
  terraform {
    source = "git::git@github.com:foo/modules.git//app?ref=v0.0.3"
  }
}

instance_count = 3
instance_type = "t2.micro"
```

And `prod/app/terraform.tfvars` may look like this:

```
terragrunt = {
  terraform {
    source = "git::git@github.com:foo/modules.git//app?ref=v0.0.1"
  }
}

instance_count = 10
instance_type = "m2.large"
```

See the [Terragrunt documentation](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

One way to resolve this is to create a `base` environment, and then symlink the common elements, for example:

```
├─ modules
├── x
├── y
├─ environments
├── base
│   ├── output.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── dev
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── output.tf -> ../base/output.tf
│   └── variables.tf -> ../base/variables.tf
├── uat
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── output.tf -> ../base/output.tf
│   └── variables.tf -> ../base/variables.tf
├── super_custom
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── output.tf # not symlinked
│   └── variables.tf # not symlinked
└── prod
    ├── main.tf
    ├── output.tf -> ../base/output.tf
    └── variables.tf -> ../base/variables.tf
```

This approach only really works if your `output.tf` and `variables.tf` files are the same for each environment, and although you can have non-symlinked variants (e.g. `super_custom` above), this can become confusing as it's not immediately obvious which environments are custom and which aren't. YMMV. I try to keep the changes between environments limited to a `.tfvars` file per environment.

It's worth reading [Charity Major's excellent post on tfstate files](https://charity.wtf/2016/03/30/terraform-vpc-and-why-you-want-a-tfstate-file-per-env/), which set me on this path.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I thought of symlinks but not a keen of this approach.. if that's the only way, I'll accept it though. Thanks for linking this post, it's really insightful, excellent read!

Comment: I've posted another answer which gets around the issue by removing the modules for each environment entirely. As it sounds like your environments are very similar, that might be an even cleaner approach. If not, could you expand your question with more information about the sorts of differences you have between environments?

Answer (score 0):

If your `dev`, `uat` and `prod` environments have the same shape, but different properties you could leverage [workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html) to separate your environment state, along with separate `*.tfvars` files to specify the different configurations.

This could look like:

```
├─ modules
│   ├── x
│   └── y
├── dev.tfvars
├── prod.tfvars
├── uat.tfvars
├── main.tf
├── outputs.tf
└── variables.tf
```

You can create a new workspace with:

```
terraform workspace new uat
```

Then deploying changes becomes:

```
terraform workspace select uat
terraform apply --var-file=uat.tfvars
```

The workspaces feature ensures that different environments states are managed separately, which is a bonus.

This approach only works when the differences between the environments are small enough that it makes sense to encapsulate the logic for that in the individual modules (for example, having a `high_availability` flag which adds some additional redundant infrastructure for `uat` and `prod`).

Comment: We considered this approach too but personally I find it way too dangerous. Just once someone forgets to set the correct state file upon invoking `terraform` and we are already in a huge trouble.. Also we are using a shared S3 state for our scripts, I'm not sure it would even work with this approach.

Comment: Also, I believe Terraform's own homepage lists this as an antipattern in the Best Practices section, so that's probably not the best approach according to them either :(

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? Workspaces were designed to be used one-per-environment (https://www.terraform.io/docs/enterprise/guides/recommended-practices/part3.3.html#3-design-your-organization-s-workspace-structure). I agree it sounds risky if you type the commands by hand, but we got around that by wrapping those commands into a single script, so you're always consistent.

Comment: Also potentially relevant, there's an open feature request to automatically load the relevant workspace .tfvars file (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12845).

Comment: yes, see https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html, "Best practises" paragraph. I would also emphasise this part: "_Workspaces alone are useful for isolating a set of resources to test changes during development. For example, it is common to associate a branch in a VCS with a temporary workspace so new features can be developed without affecting the default workspace._". Based on this, I don't think workspaces are the best fit for this problem.

Comment: Hi @KristofJozsa, I think that section is saying that workspaces *should* be used for this class of problem, however if you have complex configuration differences you should *also* be using `terraform_remote_state` to encapsulate the configuration into each module. When they say "Workspaces alone", they mean "Workspaces are useful as the only isolation mechanism for dev", not "Workspaces are only useful for isolating dev"